# Batch script -> find a sentence and replace it by a new one

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a DOS script in order to search a line and replace it into files from a specific folder. Here is what i have already done :

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class }^)"
set "replace=@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class, ReportInterceptor.class, CorrelationIdInterceptor }^)"

set "textFile=C:\Utilisateurs\a669884\Documents\test.txt"

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
echo "%%a"
for /f "Delims=" %%i  in (%%a ^& break ^> %%a) do (
    set "line=%%i "
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>%%a echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
      )
 )
```

Problem is that my first line is not replace by the new one, the new line is added under it like that :

@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class })

@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class, ReportInterceptor.class, CorrelationIdInterceptor })

Do you know why my first line isn't replaced? Thanks a lot
Seb

Comment: How is this related to Java ?

Comment: In a certain way, i will use it on my java project in order to replace a line in my WebServices

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's nothing like for loop or delayed expansion in DOS. Anyway it's better to use powershell for tasks like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what setting `textfile` has to do with the routine - it's not used.

Your original code produced a complaint that `&` was not found and created an empty file for me.

Changing the `for` to

```
for /f "Delims=" %%i  in ('type "%%a" ^& break ^> "%%a"') do (
```

seemed to make the substitution, given the one line (partial?) of sourcefile you've provided, plus a few dummy lines.

execute the `type...` with the filenames enclosed in quotes to ensure correct operation with separators, replacing the file; substitute as specified.