# Insert line in a file with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to insert an import in all my java classes, in order to do that I need a batch script. I have already made this :

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set inputFile=C:\Utilisateurs\a669884\Documents\script.txt
set outputFile=C:\Utilisateurs\a669884\Documents\script.txt
set "_strInsert=import java.test"
set "_strFind=import java.Interceptors.RunTimeExceptionInterceptor"
set i=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN (`FIND /N "%_strFind%" 
"%inputFile%"`) DO (set _strNum=%%A)
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
set /a i = !i! + 1
ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
IF [!i!] == [%_strNum%] (ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%")
)
```

In my script.txt i have this at the beginning (without the batch) :

```
import java.Interceptors.RunTimeExceptionInterceptor
```

Problem is that after starting the batch, I find a copy of the line that I search+ the line that I want to add :

```
 import java.Interceptors.RunTimeExceptionInterceptorimport 
    java.Interceptors.RunTimeExceptionInterceptor
    import java.test
```

Just like this...
Can you help me in order to have only the line that i search + the line that I want to add in the txt, without the copy of the first line
Thank you very much, Seb

Comment: This is exactly the same as your question from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029569/batch-script-find-a-sentence-and-replace-it-by-a-new-one with different search/replace strings.

Comment: Oh yes thanks I forgot that before my modifications the line was added under the first one ! sorry :)

Comment: @Magoo maybe you know how can I do a carriage return between my two strings? this can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a [set of] string[s] - using the code from yesterday

```
if "%%i "=="!line:%search%=%replace%!" (
 >>%%a echo(!line!
) else (
 >>%%a echo(replacement line 1
 >>%%a echo(replacement line 2
 >>%%a echo(replacement line 3
 >>%%a echo(replacement line 4
)
```

where your `replace` string may be empty if you like. The idea is simply to use the same technique (so you can substitute within the line or replace the line completely at will)

`replacement line *` may be simply *nothing* for an empty line.

Another technique would be

```
if "%%i "=="!line:%search%=%replace%!" (
 >>%%a echo(!line!
) else (
 >>%%a type filecontainingreplacementlinesequence.txt
)
```

Again, this is simply using the same technique.

```
if "%%i "=="%search% " (
```

could also be used to detect the significant line.

Comment: Thanks for your help Magoo